# Kies unable to connect to Samsung Galaxy S3 after rooting

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies

After I rooted my Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 phone, I was no longer able to connect to Kies to do a sync. Does anyone know why?

I have tried to reinstall Kies on my laptop, performed "Troubleshoot connection error", and deactivated USB-Debugging BEFORE I connected my phone for the first time. But the same issues remained.

When I performed *#1234# to view SW version, the PDA option was not one of the options there.

There are no issues with my USB connections as I have no problem downloading apps from Google Play on my laptop.

Pls advise how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't connect my S3 to Kies and tried everything other users posted (usb debugging, scanning pc for viruses, etc...) and I stumbled upon the fix that solved my issue and I've now connected with Kies and have full functionality with Kies and no issues with my S3.

### THE FIX:

On the S3 device:

- Pull down from top of home screen (swipe from top of screen downward) to the screen that shows (across the top) Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc...
- Check to see how the device is connected "**Connected as a Media Device**" should be shown.
- Mine said "**Connected as a camera**" and I changed that to "**Connected as a Media Device**" and instantly connected to Kies.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I realised that the problem lies with a MTP device driver which was not properly installed. All I had to do was delete all the drivers, including Samsung Kies, and reinstall everything again.

One of the other thing I did before the issue appeared, was installing SGS3 Easy UMS. Because I switched my phone from MTP to UMS mode, that prevented my laptop from detecting the phone. Switching it back to MTP, and reinstalling the above applications did help.

However, I would continue to encounter connectivity issues every now and then. For instance, after I plugged my phone into my laptop via USB, and switch to syncing using Kies Air, I would encounter an error message that says my USB is plugged in.

This could be easily resolved by restarting my phone.

I can only conclude that Samsung Kies developer probably didn't do a good job handling socket connections, resulting in the error above.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after rooting my S3. The solution is easy: just unroot your phone and like magic your old driver will work correctly.